# Converting the construct "new String[]{"", ""}" into a javascript call to a method

Tags: java, javascript, string

I'm trying to call a java method out of javascript (converted with rhino I think):

```
runner.runScript(new File(script,"test.py"), script, new String[]{"", ""}, null);
```

My problem is that i don't know how to convert the java array. My last try with this code

```
var $stringArray = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(java.lang.String, 1);
$stringArray[0] = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(java.lang.String, 2);
```

gave me an:

```
Can't find method org.sikuli.scriptrunner.JythonScriptRunner.runScript(string,string,[Ljava.lang.String;,null).
```

Maybe some can get me on the right direction?

Comment: Are you quite sure you're dealing with JavaScript? Looks a lot like you're dealing with Python/Jython...

Comment: I'm sure. I'm calling a java-lib (sikuli) from sahi (which is javascript). sikuli works with Jython.

Comment: Are you sure that your problem is the String Array? I saw in your exception code the first paramn is a String, and when you call you pass a File